# get text from attribute and format it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div elements with `data-seat` and `data-row` property:

```
<div class='selected' data-seat='1' data-row='1'></div>
<div class='selected' data-seat='2' data-row='1'></div> 
<div class='selected' data-seat='3' data-row='1'></div> 
<div class='selected' data-seat='1' data-row='2'></div>
<div class='selected' data-seat='2' data-row='2'></div>
```

I want print friendly message for selected seats:

```
var  selectedPlaceTextFormated =''; 
$(".selected").each(function () {

        var selectedPlace = $(this);

        selectedPlaceTextFormated += "Row " + selectedPlace.attr("data-row") + " (seat " + selectedPlace.attr("data-seat") + ")\n";
    });
alert(selectedPlaceTextFormated);
```

This code works well and shows the following:

```
Row 1 (seat 1)
Row 1 (seat 2)
Row 1 (seat 3)
Row 2 (seat 1)
Row 2 (seat 2)
```

But, I want group seats by row, i.e I want the following:

```
Row 1(seats: 1,2,3)
Row 2(seats: 1,2)
```

also, order by row number. How can I do this?
Thanks. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gJFJW/1/)

Comment: +1 detailed question with js fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code

```
var selectedPlaceTextFormated ='';
var row_array = [];

$(".selected").each(function () {
    var selectedPlace = $(this);
    if (!row_array[selectedPlace.attr("data-row")]){
      row_array[selectedPlace.attr("data-row")] = selectedPlace.attr("data-seat");
    }
    else row_array[selectedPlace.attr("data-row")] += ','+selectedPlace.attr("data-seat");
});

for (row in row_array){
    alert("Row "+ row +"(seat " + row_array[row] + ")\n" );
}
```

And here the link to the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gVHg/

Answer (score 2):

First of all, jQuery is kind enough to automatically grab `data-` attributes into its `data expando` object, that means, you can access those data via:

```
jQueryObject.data('seat');
```

for instance.

Your actual question could get solved like

```
var $selected      = $('.selected'),
    availableRows  = [ ],
    selectedPlaceTextFormated = '',
    currentRow,
    currentSeats;

 $selected.each(function(_, node) {
     if( availableRows.indexOf( currentRow = $(node).data('row') ) === -1 ) {
         availableRows.push( currentRow );
     }
 });

 availableRows.forEach(function( row ) {
     selectedPlaceTextFormated += 'Row ' + row + '(';

     currentSeats = $selected.filter('[data-row=' + row + ']').map(function(_, node) {
         return $(this).data('seat');
     }).get();

    selectedPlaceTextFormated += currentSeats.join(',') + ')\n';
 });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gJFJW/3/

Comment: Thanks for `data expando` and solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another variable to store the row, and format accordingly.

```
var selectedPlaceTextFormated =''; 
var prevRow = 0;
$(".selected").each(function () {
    var selectedPlace = $(this);
    var row = selectedPlace.attr("data-row");
    var seat = selectedPlace.attr("data-seat");
    if(prevRow == row){
        selectedPlaceTextFormated += "," + seat;
    }
    else{
        if(selectedPlaceTextFormated != ''){
            selectedPlaceTextFormated += ')\n';
        }
        selectedPlaceTextFormated += "Row " + row + " (seat " + seat;
        prevRow = row;
    }

});
selectedPlaceTextFormated += ')\n';
alert(selectedPlaceTextFormated);
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/R8HHC/

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a few slight modifications to your existing code to use arrays; these arrays are then used to build a string:

```
var selectedPlaceTextFormated = [];
var textFormatted = '';
$(".selected").each(function(i) {

    var selectedPlace = $(this);
    var arr = [];

    selectedPlaceTextFormated[selectedPlace.attr("data-row")] += "," + selectedPlace.attr("data-seat");

});

selectedPlaceTextFormated.shift();

for (var i = 0; i < selectedPlaceTextFormated.length; i++) {
    var arr2 = selectedPlaceTextFormated[i].split(",");
    arr2.shift();
    textFormatted += "Row " + (i + 1) + " seats: (" + arr2.join(",") + ")\n";
}

alert(textFormatted);
```

​
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/kcKNQ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do this:

```
var text = []; 
$(".selected").each(function () {
    var a = parseInt($(this).data('row'), 10),
        b = $(this).data('seat');
    text[a] = ((text[a])?text[a]+', ':'')+b;
});

var selectedPlaceTextFormated ='';
$.each(text, function(index, elem) {
    if (!this.Window) selectedPlaceTextFormated += "Row " + index + " (seat " + elem + ")\n";
});

alert(selectedPlaceTextFormated);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gJFJW/5/)